# Swift - UIView moves when changing tab controller tabs

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitabbarcontroller

Inside the `viewDidAppear` I have a function that contains this code, in order to make a `UIView`:

```
let contentView = UIView()
    func addSleepingView() {
        
        contentView.backgroundColor = .systemYellow.withAlphaComponent(0.25)
        
        view.addSubview(contentView)
        
        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        
        // Anchor your view right above the tabBar
        contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (tabBarController?.tabBar.topAnchor)!).isActive = true
        contentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Test"
        label.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 34.0)
        label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(label)
        label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "arrow.clockwise", withConfiguration: UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(scale: .large)), for: UIControl.State.normal)
        button.tintColor = .systemGray
        button.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.width-42, y: 8, width: 34, height: 34.0)
        button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(wakeupFunction), for: .touchUpInside)
        contentView.addSubview(button)
        let button2 = UIButton()
        button2.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "exclamationmark.triangle", withConfiguration: UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(scale: .large)), for: UIControl.State.normal)
        button2.tintColor = .label
        button2.frame = CGRect(x: 8, y: 8, width: 34, height: 34.0)
        button2.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        contentView.addSubview(button2)
        
        contentView.bringSubviewToFront(button)
    }
```

This is what it looks like:
[image]

Now this is exactly how I want it. The problem comes when I change tab. For example go to the last tab, and back to the first tab again. Then it looks like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add your code of activating constraints inside the **DispatchQueue.main** block

Updated Line you can change and it will start working as you're expectation.

// Anchor your view right above the tabBar

```
DispatchQueue.main.async 
{

        self.contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (self.tabBarController?.tabBar.topAnchor)!).isActive = true
        self.contentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    }
```